# Can I create two different graphql query for two different folders separately in my Gatsby project

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm a newbie programmer and Recently I want to add a blog page to my website. I already have a projects page using Graphql and .md files, now my problem is, every time I try to create a blog post with .md, it appears also in my projects page, could you please advice me with some of your kind experience on solving this issue and do I have to create a separate query? even I don't know how?

this is my current query.

```
export const query = graphql`
  query ProjectsPage {
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        frontmatter {
          slug
          stack
          title
          thumb {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, layout: FULL_WIDTH)
            }
          }
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy thing you can do is to add a `key` field on your markdown files to distinguish between posts and projects. This will allow you to filter GraphQL queries. In the same way, you can also place the markdowns in separate folders and filter them using the relative/absolute path.

```
export const query = graphql`
  query ProjectsPage {
    allMarkdownRemark(filter: { frontmatter: {key: { eq: "project" }}, sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        frontmatter {
          slug
          stack
          title
          thumb {
            childImageSharp {
              gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED, layout: FULL_WIDTH)
            }
          }
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
```

As I said, this approach assumes that you have created a `key: project` field in your markdown files. You can do the same using `key: article`.

Alternatively, placing the markdowns in different folders using `fileAbsolutePath`/`relativePath` if needed in the same way. This approach will rely on your filesystem structure to determine the available paths. Both approaches are based on a filtered query, choose whatever suits you better.

Use the GraphiQL playground to test all queries, paths and filters at `localhost:8000/___graphql`

Comment: Thank You @FerranBuireu , I used the first method which is by adding a `key` field and it works fine now